# HTML Forms not working well on all my browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet, browser, internet-explorer

Buttons, Drop down lists, check boxes, etc. from some websites not working in any of my web browsers.

**Buttons from bootsnip site**
I cant view html code of any exaple by clicking its HTML, CSS, preivew buttons. they are not working.
[image: HTML,CSS, JS buttons here]

**Drop down lists not loading**

Only 2 Drop down lists from this site is not loading. 
[image: Image preivew]

**Checkboxes not loading**
Cannot see "I am not robot" checkbox in this one. everytime i click login it saying click I am not robot, bt I cant see it. Everytime I'm trying to login it saying click "I am not roobot". But I cant see it.

*I cannot post 3rd pic because i dont have enough reputation points for that.*

**My Computer**
Asus X555L i5 5th gen laptop
Running Windows 10

**What I tried**

- I reset all my browsers.
- I re-installed them.
- Manually enabled javascript settings.
- reset ipv4,ipv6 settings.
- flushed dns, reset proxyports, tcp settings etc.

Not worked any. Any solutions?

Comment: Open dev tools in Chrome and see if any URI is being blocked. Could be due to a failure, the control is being rendered correctly

Comment: I checked it and it has these errors. `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `Mixed Content: The page at` [link]https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/vertical-affix-menu-css-only was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'. `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the drop down lists are not failing, only some of them are, it would suggest it's potentitally a scripting issue. My guess is there are some resources which are being blocked

In Chrome or IE, hit F12 to get up the dev tools and see if any resources are failing to load in the network tab.

Then you can see the reasons why - it could lots of reason, such as a corporate network, your firewall, your ISP or just a fault with the visited website...

**Edit**

As per your comments which I've combined `I checked it and it has these errors. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and Mixed Content: The page at [link]bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/vertical-affix-menu-cs‌​s-only was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/…;. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS` and `But using my android phone I can access all that sites properly using same WiFi connection. I tried different network connection to my computer and result is the same`

This suggests you've got some add on (I know you've re-installed but it's not clear if you reinstalled all/any add ons), or on your PC it's the firewall or antivirus/internet security.

It could be something via the hosts file... It could be you're using a different DNS. There are many possible reasons here.

Comment: I just checked and there is error `Failed to load response data` for several js(java script) and css files.  But using my android phone I can access all that sites properly using same WiFi connection. I tried different network connection to my computer and result is the same.

Comment: Well Thank you, It was problem with my host file. I had blocked some CDN links and googleapi link in there. Thank you again